# Reading Data and Writing into same excel file

Tags: java, excel

I want to read the data from one tab of excel file and write to a specific column of another tab in the same excel file using java.Could you please help me in out in providing some solution.Thanks in advance.

My Code Looks like :

```
public  String [][] getExcelData() throws Exception{

String [][] tabArray = null;

            FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream("C:\\SCE docs\\Automation\\CustomerAccount_Information.xls"); 
            HSSFWorkbook myWB = new HSSFWorkbook(fi); 
            HSSFSheet mySheet = myWB.getSheetAt(0); 

            FormulaEvaluator evaluator = myWB.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();

            xRows = mySheet.getLastRowNum()+1; 
            xCols = mySheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum(); 


            tabArray = new String [xRows][xCols]; 

            for (int i=0;i<xRows;i++) 
            { 
            HSSFRow row = mySheet.getRow(i); 
            for (int j=3;j<xCols;j++) 
            { 
                HSSFCell cell = row.getCell(j); 
                CellValue cellValue = evaluator.evaluate(cell);
                String value = evaluateFormula(cellValue);
                tabArray[i][j]=value;

         }
            }
            return tabArray;

            }

private String evaluateFormula(CellValue cellValue) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

int type = cellValue.getCellType();

Object result = null;

switch (type) {

case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
    result = cellValue.getBooleanValue();
     break;
 case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
     result = cellValue.getNumberValue();
     break;
 case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
     result = cellValue.getStringValue();
     break;
 case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
     break;
 case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR:
     break;


 // CELL_TYPE_FORMULA will never happen
 case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA: 
     break;
}

return result.toString();
}
            }
```

The Output i am getting is

```
 Cust Num null
 Cust Num CustAccNum
 Cust Num null
 Cust Num 2-23-456-7891
 Cust Num null
 Cust Num 2-00-006-7891
 Cust Num null
 Cust Num 2-03-456-7891
 Cust Num null
 Cust Num 2-00-234-5678
 Cust Num null
 Cust Num 2-00-023-4891
 Cust Num null
 Cust Num 2-00-234-7891
 Cust Num null
 Cust Num 2-00-345-6781
```

Help Needed: I dont want the null value which has been initialized for object result to be displayed. Could you please provide a work arround.

Comment: Java != JavaScript. Which one do you actually want to use?

Comment: which excel format: xlsx or csv?

Comment: Java, and the file format i want to use is xls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In java you can achieve this by using third party libraries. One good library is POI by Apache. Please refer the below link for more information:

[Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/)

You can manipulate almost all types of office documents with the help of Apache POI API's.

Comment: Thank you but my code is not sending the required information. please check the above code

Comment: I Have resolved it thank you. please ignore the above comment.